# Javascript - Click Button to FadeIn, FadeOut by clicking anywhere

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout

I want my navigation to fade-in when a special button is clicked, and to fade away when the user is clicking somewhere else - doesn't matter where.

My Script looks like this:

```
function showText() {
    var spoiler = document.getElementById('spoiler');
    var button  = document.getElementById('navicon');

    if (spoiler.style.display == 'block') {
       spoiler.style.display='none';
       button.value = 'Text einblenden';
    } else {

      spoiler.style.display='block';
      button.value = 'Text ausblenden';
     }
    return false;
}
```

My workaround was to give every navigation element the following code snippet.

```
onclick="$('#thedivlayeriwanttofadeout').fadeOut('slow');"
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you post your navigation HTML?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? The way to handle this would be to take advantage of event bubbling and attach an event handler to a common parent (e.g. body).

Comment: Also, if you are using jQuery (as you click handler body suggests) then use jQuery and get rid of all the `document.getElementById` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use bubbling to attach a single click handler to a common parent element (for example, `body`).

Here's a simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nzqNP/):

```
$(function () {
    $("#myButton").click(function (e) {
        $("#hidden").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

    $("#parent").click(function() {
        $("#hidden").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Clicking the button will fade in the element with id `hidden`. Clicking anywhere in `parent` will fade it out again.